# The first number larger than 300 that is a multiple of both 6 and 8.

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Take a look at the [question No. 23 on Page-42](https://greworldknowlegde.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/nova-gre-math-bible.pdf).

```
Column A                                                  Column B
----------------------------------------------------------------------
The first number larger than                                 324
300 that is a multiple of both 6                           
and 8.
```

The given answer is **(B)**. I.e. Column A < Column B

How is that a correct answer?

To my understanding, since, the first number larger than 300 that is a multiple of both 6 and 8 is **324**, the answer should be **(C)**. I.e. Column A == Column B.

So, what is going on here?

Comment: $324$ is not a multiple of $8.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least common multiple of $6$ and $8$ is $24$, so the smallest number greater than $300$ that is a multiple of $24$ is $24 \cdot 13 = 312$.

Answer (score 1):

$6$ and $8$ divide $312$. $\text{ }$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $324$ is not divisible by $8$, then try with $306$, $312$ and $318$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/994399)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Are you sure about that?